# Chrome Desktop Notification doesn't display the message

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, web-push, web-notifications

I'm developing a website that supports desktop notifications. I'm utilizing GCM and Azure Notification Hub to send push messages to end users. I followed this [codelab](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en) tutorial. When testing I have found that the push notifications do get displayed on the screen, but the message that I have written in the payload is not shown in the notification. So I again went through the codelab, and they have mentioned a `body` key in the `showNotification` method.

**Code**

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('Push message', event);
    var title = 'Push message';
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(title, {
            body: 'The Message',
            icon: 'images/icon.png',
            tag: 'my-tag'
    }));
});
```

They have hardcoded  "The Message" in the `showNotification` function. I don't want to hardcode my message in the function since my message won't be the same always and will vary time to time. I want to know how to make the function take the message in payload and display it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome doesn't support push payloads yet, for now you could use them only in Firefox.

The solution is to request the payload from the server (using `fetch`) once you get a notification.

Something like this:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    fetch('./getPayload?someUniqueID=' + someUniqueID)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(payload) {
      self.registration.showNotification('Title', {
        body: payload,
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Obviously, the response can also be in JSON, so that you can specify everything (title, body, icon, etc.).

You can see an example here: https://serviceworke.rs/push-get-payload.html.

Another possible solution is to use the payload when it's available and use `fetch` otherwise. This way you can take advantage of the feature in Firefox (and in Chrome once available), and have a fallback for browsers that don't support payloads yet.
There's an example in [Mercurius](https://github.com/marco-c/mercurius/blob/master/static/sw-push.js#L3).